# ¿Estructura de ramas Git en local como la proporcionada por pull-request?

Tags: git

Si voy generando ramas Git en local y las fusiono (git merge), gráficamente
tengo una única rama sin derivaciones (imagen de la izquierda), si uso un servicio remoto como
repositorio como *github* o *bitbucked* y hago **pull-requests** al fusionar
las ramas implicadas, aunque al final queda la rama en la que se ha fusionado
el trabajo, gráficamente se obtiene una estructura en la que se pueden
diferenciar las ramas y sus diferentes *commits* de aquellas en las que derivan (imagen de la derecha).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Se puede hacer esto en local con ***comandos de Git***, cuáles serían?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes obtener exactamente lo mismo.... el truco no esta en *crear* ramas.... el truco es como las creas y luego *mezclas* las ramas.... digamos que tienes una rama `main` y tienes que hacer 3 features, con 2 commits cada uno. Arrancas feature1 desde main, 2 commits, te pasas a main, mezclas (si no se indica --no-ff, git no va a mezclar... va a colocar main en la punta de feature1)... si en este punto arrancas feature 2, va a pasar exactamente lo mismo al mezclar... lo mismo con feature 3, te queda una línea recta.

Ahora diganos que arrancamos las 3 ramas sobre main al comienzo.... hacemos checkout de feature1.... hacemos los 2 commits, mezclamos.... git va a hacer fast-forwarf de nuevo. Ahora hacemos checkout de feature 2 (que arrancó donde estaba main *antes*). 2 commits, hacemos checkout de main, ahora al hacer merge git no puede hacer fast-forward y te va a quedar la rama de feature2 separada. Igual pasaría con feature 3.